# Firebase Push to real-time database not working

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, push

I am trying to push values into the **firebase realtime database** in **react-native**. Very basic query, it's not working. Please check out the code.

Tried to push the data from the starting component `App.js` as well as relevant component's `componentDidMount()` and other relevant methods, the events are not firing.

Changed the configuration by linking a different project in firebase, still not working.

../config/db.js

```
import Firebase from 'firebase';

var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "--",
    authDomain: "--.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "---d33c8.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "---d33c8",
    storageBucket: "---d33c8.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "--",
    appId: "--",
    measurementId: "--"
  };
let app = Firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const db = app.database();
```

App.js

```
 import { db } from './src/config/db';

 db.ref().child('items').push({
     title : "1",
     description: "2"
 });
```

[App's firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klNWk.png)

The data is not going through. No errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the rules inside your realtime database are set to this to allow not authorized users to read and write, if you don't have it like this, you can't read/write to the database

```
{
  /* Visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security to learn more about security rules. */
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

> By default, your database rules require Firebase Authentication and
>   grant full read and write permissions only to authenticated users. The
>   default rules ensure your database isn't accessible by just anyone
>   before you get a chance to configure it.

Check out: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart#sample-rules

Comment: Thanks @Gastón Saillén, that was the problem.

Comment: No problem, can you mark the answe as correct ? Thanks